# How does this self inner join query is working?

Tags: mysql

```
Activity table:
+-----------+-----------+------------+--------------+
| player_id | device_id | event_date | games_played |
+-----------+-----------+------------+--------------+
| 1         | 2         | 2016-03-01 | 5            |
| 1         | 2         | 2016-05-02 | 6            |
| 1         | 3         | 2017-06-25 | 1            |
| 3         | 1         | 2016-03-02 | 0            |
| 3         | 4         | 2018-07-03 | 5            |
+-----------+-----------+------------+--------------+
Output: 
+-----------+------------+---------------------+
| player_id | event_date | games_played_so_far |
+-----------+------------+---------------------+
| 1         | 2016-03-01 | 5                   |
| 1         | 2016-05-02 | 11                  |
| 1         | 2017-06-25 | 12                  |
| 3         | 2016-03-02 | 0                   |
| 3         | 2018-07-03 | 5                   |
+-----------+------------+---------------------+
```

Query:

```
select a1.player_id, a1.event_date, sum(a2.games_played) as games_played_so_far
from activity as a1
inner join activity as a2
on a1.event_date >= a2.event_date
and a1.player_id = a2.player_id
group by  a1.player_id, a1.event_date
```

I am not able to understand how this self inner join works. Can anyone explain it a bit. I saw few videos but not helpful so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you select the data without the group by you can see better  what it does-

For every row in a2 it selects all rows from a1 that fit the criteria a1.event_date >= `a2.event_date and a1.player_id = a2.player_id` and joins them together

The group by only sums all rows in a2 up that have the same player id and a1.eventdate

What you so get is a Cumulative sum.

in MySQL 8 was this made easier with window functions.

> ```
> select a1.player_id, a1.event_date,a2.player_id, a2.event_date
> from activity as a1
> inner join activity as a2
> on a1.event_date >= a2.event_date
> and a1.player_id = a2.player_id
> ```

> ```
> player_id | event_date | player_id | event_date
> --------: | :--------- | --------: | :---------
>         1 | 2017-06-25 |         1 | 2016-03-01
>         1 | 2016-05-02 |         1 | 2016-03-01
>         1 | 2016-03-01 |         1 | 2016-03-01
>         1 | 2017-06-25 |         1 | 2016-05-02
>         1 | 2016-05-02 |         1 | 2016-05-02
>         1 | 2017-06-25 |         1 | 2017-06-25
>         3 | 2018-07-03 |         3 | 2016-03-02
>         3 | 2016-03-02 |         3 | 2016-03-02
>         3 | 2018-07-03 |         3 | 2018-07-03
> ```

> ```
> select a1.player_id, a1.event_date, sum(a2.games_played) as games_played_so_far
> from activity as a1
> inner join activity as a2
> on a1.event_date >= a2.event_date
> and a1.player_id = a2.player_id
> group by  a1.player_id, a1.event_date
> ORDER BY a1.player_id, a1.event_date
> ```
>
> ```
> player_id | event_date | games_played_so_far
> --------: | :--------- | ------------------:
>         1 | 2016-03-01 |                   5
>         1 | 2016-05-02 |                  11
>         1 | 2017-06-25 |                  12
>         3 | 2016-03-02 |                   0
>         3 | 2018-07-03 |                   5
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bc52b0b035830bc2f6e3d906cfd469b2)*